# How to sync tables between SQL Azure and SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Right now we have a SQL 2005 database in a local environment and we need to sync some tables with a SQL Azure database. We read that SSIS 2005 doesn't support Azure, so how can I do this sync?

Comment: How about setting up a linked server on SQL Server 2005 to Azure? More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/08/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SQL Azure Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx)?  As far as I know it works with SQL 2005 and would allow you to keep your local SQL 2005 database in sync with the SQL Azure database.